# How to set multiple keyboard shortcuts in Notepad++ to the same function?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, copy

I am used to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> as my shortcut for "Copy to clipboard". Also <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> for "Paste" and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> for "Cut".

Recently, these shortcuts stopped working in Notepad++. I don't remember if I updated it to latest version. When I go to Notepad++ menu "Settings" -> "Shortcut Mapper", I see that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is mapped to the "Copy" command. This is good, but I also want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> to do the same. When I try to change the mapping, it deletes the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> mapping.

How can I map two shortcuts to the same command? Is it only possible for a few commands (like Copy, Paste and Cut) and not generally?

Comment: Do you know AutoHotKey? https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/howto/WriteHotkeys.htm

Comment: Interesting stuff, I had no idea it existed! If I don't get an answer to this question, maybe I can use AutoHotKey as a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with Copy/Paste shortcuts is a regression which happened in version 8.6.1 and was fixed in version 8.6.2.

https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/14551

Notepad++ has a hard-coded table of keyboard shortcuts. Some commands (Cut, Copy, Paste and a few others) have two hard-coded shortcuts. The user can change any or both of them using Shortcut mapper. Adding a second shortcut for any other command seems impossible.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible in N++ currently and is a [requested feature](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/4859) that you can support.

There is a working workaround listed though:

> It is a pretty reasonable request. I can think of a workaround as you wait for it to be accepted and implemented though: Record and name two macros ("Close1" and "Close2"), each with a single action ("Close") and then assign each macro to a different keycombo (e.g. "Close1" to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>, "Close2" to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>).

The same can be done here with anologically. Recording can be done through **Macro** -> **Start Recording**.

---

As for [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) workaround, it should be as simple as:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad++
^Ins::Send, ^c
+Ins::Send, ^v
^Del::Send, ^x
```

Check [documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Send.htm) for info about key names and mapping.